# Function of semicolon while deleting an item from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this, I want to delete `("poolhouse", 24.5)`.

When I use semicolon it only deletes the strings. I dont know why. Isn't it supposed to delete what number I mentioned in the brackets?

Two strings are deleted `[10]` and `[12]`.

I want to know the function of semicolon.

```
areas = ["hallway", 11.25, "kitchen", 18.0,  "chill zone", 20.0, "bedroom",
         10.75, "bathroom", 10.50, "poolhouse", 24.5, "garage", 15.45]
del(areas[10]); del(areas[11])
print(areas)
```

Output:

```
['hallway', 11.25, 'kitchen', 18.0, 'chill zone', 20.0, 'bedroom', 10.75,
 'bathroom', 10.5, 24.5, 15.45]
```

Comment: After you delete index 10, everything from 10 upwards will move down by one, so your new 10 is the old 11, the new 11 is the old 12. So you should delete 10 twice, or first 11 then 10.

Comment: The semicolon just lets you put two commands on one line. You can replace it with a newline and the meaning won't change.

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon is just a way to put two statements on a single line, but generally doesn't change the behavior of your program.

As others have pointed out, deleting the element at index `[10]` causes all the following element's indices to be shifted down by one, so any subsequent operations must have any indices they specify adjusted accordingly.

Another way to delete two (or more) consecutive elements all at once, which is often simpler and faster, is by designating the range of indices by using [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings) notation and deleting all of them in a single operation.

```
areas = ["hallway", 11.25, "kitchen", 18.0,  "chill zone", 20.0, "bedroom",
         10.75, "bathroom", 10.50, "poolhouse", 24.5, "garage", 15.45]
del areas[10:12]  # selects elements 10->11 for deletion
print(areas)
```

Output:

```
['hallway', 11.25, 'kitchen', 18.0, 'chill zone', 20.0, 'bedroom', 10.75,
 'bathroom', 10.5, 'garage', 15.45]
```

The expression `areas[10:12]` means the elements starting at index `10` who's indices are *less than* the last number, `12` — so in this case `areas[10]` and `areas[11]` respectively in the original list.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete the item at index 10, all the items after index 10 get moved up. Either correct this to:

```
del areas[10], areas[11]
```

or use the `remove` method on your list:

```
for i in ("poolhouse", 24.5): areas.remove(i)
```